# How to check Kotlin coroutine job.isActive in the calling method

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to use Kotlin coroutine instead of legacy Java thread to perform background actions:

I learned from this [link](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/cancellation-in-coroutines-aa6b90163629) and it works fine

```
val job = launch {
    for(file in files) {
        ensureActive() //will throw cancelled exception to interrupt the execution
        readFile(file)
    }
}
```

But my case is that I have a very complex calling function of readFile(), how can I check whether the job is active inside that function?

```
val job = launch {
    for(file in files) {
        ensureActive() //will throw cancelled exception to interrupt the execution
        complexFunOfReadingFile(file) //may process each line of the file
    }
}
```

I don't want to copy the impl of the function inside this coroutine scope or pass the job instance as a parameter into that function.
What is official way to handle this case?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make `complexFunOfReadingFile()` a `suspend` function and put periodic `yield()` or `ensureActive()` calls in it.

Example:

```
suspend fun foo(file: File) {
    file.useLines { lineSequence ->
        for (line in lineSequence) {
            yield() // or coroutineContext.ensureActive()            
            println(line)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, can you give a sample? I tried todo: suspend fun readFile(): Boolean{ while(str = readLine()) {ensureActive() //then process the str} } but I got error inside this suspend function: Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: public fun CoroutineContext.ensureActive(): Unit defined in kotlinx.coroutines
public fun CoroutineScope.ensureActive(): Unit defined in kotlinx.coroutines
public fun Job.ensureActive(): Unit defined in kotlinx.coroutines

Comment: I added a sample. If you use a higher-order function that is not inline, such as `File.forEachLine`, then you don't have access to the coroutine context within the lambda. `File.useLines` is inline.

Comment: One more question related with this: I am getting "Inappropriate blocking method call" IDE warning if I don't wrap my file io operation with "withContext(Dispatchers.IO)". Do I have to wrap it as I am already only calling it from CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {} block. I tried to annotate the suspend function with @Workthread, the warning is still there.

Comment: It's appropriate to always wrap suspend functions that use IO in `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` so they can safely be used from anywhere. IIRC, the convention is that any suspend function should be safe to call from the Main dispatcher. I think that's the reason for that warning. But, I have occasionally seen that warning give false positives or missed negatives.

Comment: Really thanks. So I guess as long as I can make sure this function is only called in CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {} block, I can ignore this warning and go without wrapping with withContext(Dispatchers.IO){}? Adding it will make my return logic to be changed a lot in that suspend function.

Comment: I guess, but I'm having trouble picturing how wrapping in `withContext` could affect the internal logic.

Comment: I am getting error saying "return is not allowed here" when I tried to return early inside the withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { if(condition) return null} block

Comment: Use `return@withContext` since you're inside a lambda.

Comment: Oh, that is great. Thanks a lot for your patient help.